How to click an element with randomized selector?
I'm trying to click the "What's on your mind" input on a Facebook user profile. I can do that in the browser:
const whatsOnYourMind = document.querySelector("#mount_0_0_Xr > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.x9f619.x1n2onr6.x1ja2u2z > div > div > div.x78zum5.xdt5ytf.x1t2pt76.x1n2onr6.x1ja2u2z.x10cihs4 > div.x78zum5.xdt5ytf.x1t2pt76 > div > div > div.x6s0dn4.x78zum5.xdt5ytf.x193iq5w > div.x9f619.x193iq5w.x1talbiv.x1sltb1f.x3fxtfs.x1swvt13.x1pi30zi.xw7yly9 > div > div.x9f619.x1n2onr6.x1ja2u2z.xeuugli.xs83m0k.xjl7jj.x1xmf6yo.x1emribx.x1e56ztr.x1i64zmx.x19h7ccj.xu9j1y6.x7ep2pv > div:nth-child(1) > div > div > div > div > div.x1cy8zhl.x78zum5.x1iyjqo2.xh8yej3 > div > div.x1ey2m1c.xds687c.x17qophe.xg01cxk.x47corl.x10l6tqk.x13vifvy.x1ebt8du.x19991ni.x1dhq9h.x1o1ewxj.x3x9cwd.x1e5q0jg.x13rtm0m")
whatsOnYourMind.click()

However, the element returns null when I use @astral/astral on Deno (the browser is logged in already):
import { launch } from "jsr:@astral/astral";
const browser = await launch({ headless: false });
const page = await browser.newPage("https://www.facebook.com/my_own_profile");
const whatsOnYourMind = await page.$("#mount_0_0_Xr > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.x9f619.x1n2onr6.x1ja2u2z > div > div > div.x78zum5.xdt5ytf.x1t2pt76.x1n2onr6.x1ja2u2z.x10cihs4 > div.x78zum5.xdt5ytf.x1t2pt76 > div > div > div.x6s0dn4.x78zum5.xdt5ytf.x193iq5w > div.x9f619.x193iq5w.x1talbiv.x1sltb1f.x3fxtfs.x1swvt13.x1pi30zi.xw7yly9 > div > div.x9f619.x1n2onr6.x1ja2u2z.xeuugli.xs83m0k.xjl7jj.x1xmf6yo.x1emribx.x1e56ztr.x1i64zmx.x19h7ccj.xu9j1y6.x7ep2pv > div:nth-child(1) > div > div > div > div > div.x1cy8zhl.x78zum5.x1iyjqo2.xh8yej3 > div > div.x1ey2m1c.xds687c.x17qophe.xg01cxk.x47corl.x10l6tqk.x13vifvy.x1ebt8du.x19991ni.x1dhq9h.x1o1ewxj.x3x9cwd.x1e5q0jg.x13rtm0m");
whatsOnYourMind.click()

Why is that?

Those class names (div.x78zum5.xdt5ytf.x1t2pt76..) look programmatically generated, I doubt they remain the same between page loads.

at first I thought so, but I try reloading the page several times and the browser code still seems to work.
